# How to submit form when Enter is pressed in PrimeFaces selectOneMenu?

Tags: primefaces

I'm having a form which contains only selectOneMenu inputs and a submit button. When I press Enter in the selectOneMenu nothing happens. If I have a text input in the form, the form is submitted when I press Enter and focus is in the text input, but is is never submitted if focus is in a selectOneMenu.

You can see the same behavior in the PrimeFaces ShowCase here: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajax/dropdown.xhtml

Is there a way to make Enter in a selectOneMenu input submit the form? And Enter should only submit the form, if the menu is not shown, as Enter here is used to select a value.

I've tried to catch the keypress using jQuery, but it's never called when pressing Enter - other keypresses are being caught.

I'm using PrimeFaces 5.3.

Thanks!

/Brian

Comment: Behaviour confirmed in the showcase. To solve it, please look at the source of the corresponding PrimeFaces js file and see if something in there is  blocking this. You can then override the PrimeFaces javascript and get the right behaviour. Also please check the PF issuelist in GitHub and see if it is fixed in a 5.3.x and/or 6.0-SNAPSHOT. If not, please file an issue there

Comment: Thanks - I managed to make it work by overriding the PrimeFaces javascript. Anf I've filed an issue on PF GitHub.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to make et work by overriding the handleEnterKey of SelectOneMenu in which I only call event.preventDefault and event.stopPropagation when the menu is visible. In the PrimeFaces 5.3 version event.preventDefault and event.stopPropagation are always called whether or not the menu is visible (and thereby blocking the Enter key).

```
PrimeFaces.widget.SelectOneMenu.prototype.handleEnterKey = function(event) {
    if (this.panel.is(':visible')) {
        this.selectItem(this.getActiveItem());
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
    }
}
```

PrimeFaces issue: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/1127#issuecomment-182269814

Comment: Thanks, this is how opensource should work. Hope hey include your patch in an elite release and 6.0.